# The source branch is 1 commit behind the target branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I see following message on a merge request I created -

```
The source branch is 1 commit behind the target branch.
```

I'm able to push changes to my merge request however I'm 1 commit behind the master commit.

[image]

[image]

Question :

My `some_changes` branch is on a master branch which is 1 commit behind the current master branch.

I've a merge request request with all changes yet to be merged to `master`.

Now another person has already pushed a commit to master and now for me with my branch `some_changes` I'm 1 commit behind the `master`.

Now to make my `some_changes` to have `master` branch which is up to date and not 1 commit behind the `master` which is pushed by another person.

How to fix this ?

Comment: Your source branch doesn't have anything *new* to master, so merging it into master has no effect. But what's the question here?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: I've added more explanation to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Your image shows what's going on.  Unfortunately the image is hard to read (tiny, and, well, an *image*).  But it does show the problem.  Explaining the problem in words, and drawing it in text, requires a bit of background.

A *Git repository* consists primarily of *commits*.  Each commit *in* some repository:

- Has a unique ID (a "hash ID", which command-line Git will show you as either abbreviated, such as `a123456`, or in full).  These things *look* random—though they're not at all random—and are not very useful for humans, so a lot of graphical commit viewers, including yours, omit them.  Sometimes that's good, and sometimes that's a terrible disservice to you; in this case it's more a little bit of both.
- Stores two things:

  - Every commit stores a full snapshot of every file.  These act like permanent archives.  The files *in* this snapshot are stored in a special, compressed, and *de-duplicated*, Git-only format.  When you make a new commit, you'll generally re-use almost every file from the previous commit.  Through the de-duplication trick, Git won't actually *store* those files *again*.  Nonetheless, each commit "has" all the files: they're just *shared*, automatically, without you having to think or worry about it.

    This sharing has a strong consequence: no part of any existing commit can ever be changed, not even by Git itself.  (Git's hashing technique depends on this as well.)  Commits are therefore entirely read-only, once made.  They're also mostly permanent, though you can "eject a commit off the end of a branch" in some cases.
  - Every commit stores some *metadata*.  This includes things like the name and email address of the person who made the commit, and some date-and-time stamps.  It also includes a *log message* where you describe *why* you made the commit: yours read `Initial commit`, `pushing a file`, `pushing xyz file to branch`, and `pushing pqr file to branch`.

    Git includes, in this metadata, the raw hash ID of the *previous* commit.  In this way, every commit remembers which commit you used in order to create it.

As we already noted, each commit is read-only.  Git finds the commit by its hash ID, not—well, not *yet*—by a branch name.  Commits may be on multiple branches, or even on no branch at all, so there's no way to go from commit to branch name.  So: what *is* a branch name, and what does one do for you?

You have two branch names in your repository: `master` and `some_changes`.  Your graphical viewer shows you these as a sort of label, attached to a colored dot that represents some commit.  Horizontally to the right of the colored dot, your viewer shows you the log message (or at least its first line).  This arranges the commits in time, sort of, with newer commits higher up towards the top of the window:

```
master ----------> * pushing pqr file to branch
some_changes --> * | pushing xyz file to branch
                  \|
                   * pushing a file
                   * initial commit
```

This is an attempt to show you all commits at once, without having "time" get in the way very much.  But it doesn't work.  Time gets right there in the way: your latest commit is at the top and your earliest commit is at the bottom.

I like to draw these commits differently.  I tend to use a single uppercase letter to stand in for a commit hash: `H` stands for "hash", for instance.  Commit `H` holds inside itself—in its metadata—the raw, random-looking hash ID of some earlier commit `G`.  Both commits hold full snapshots of every file, as of the form those files had when you made those commits.  Commit `G` holds in its metadata the raw hash ID of still-earlier commit `F`, and so on.

When these are all in a row, we get a linear chain, which I draw left-to-right, with newer commits towards the *right*, like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--branch-name
```

The *branch name* holds the raw hash ID of the *latest commit*.  It's a label—just like your viewer drew—and it allows Git to *find* commit `H`, because the name holds the hash ID *of* `H`.

Sometimes, though, our commits aren't all neatly linear:

```
     C   <-- master
    /
A--B
    \
     D   <-- some_changes
```

Here we have *two* labels, `master` and `some_changes`.  The name `master` points to commit `C`, which is the latest.  The name `some_changes` points to commit `D`, **which is also the latest**.  There are *two* "latest" commits.  To draw this "correctly" (for some definition of correct), we can't just put them all in a row, either horizontally *or* vertically.  Hence in my text diagram I put the branch names and arrows at the far right, and have them point leftward to the latest commits.  Those commits then point further left—in this case, down-and-left from `C` to `B`, and up-and-left from `D` to `B`—so as to find, for Git, the *parent commit*.

In this way, commits `A` and `B` are on *both branches*.  That's because we can find them by starting at `C` and working backwards **and** by starting at `D` and working backwards.

The job of `git merge` is to *combine work*, and Git will often be able to do that all on its own.  In GitLab (but not Git—Git does not have "merge requests"), a *merge request* is a way to identify two particular commits—in this case, `C` or `pushing pqr file to branch`, and `D` or `pushing xyz file to branch`—and ask that some human make Git merge those two commits.

Note that commit `C` is not *before* commit `D`, nor is it *after* commit `D`.  The two commits are both one commit after `B`, but the two commits are actually parallel.  *After* a successful merge, however, we'll have this:

```
     C
    / \
A--B   M
    \ /
     D
```

where `M` is a new *merge commit* that *combines the work done in the two branches*.  I've deliberately removed all the branch name labels here: Git only uses them to (help you) *find* commits; it's the actual *commits* that really matter.  Of course, since humans *do* use names to find commits, the name that ultimately ends up pointing to commit `M` will matter *to you*.  It just won't matter to *Git*.

#### Linear "merges"

Some people like it when proposed merges are all linear:

```
W--X--Y   <-- master
       \
        Z   <-- branch
```

Here commit `Z` is one commit ahead of commit `Y`.  As you can see, there's no other "branch-y" structure sticking out: unlike our `A-B` case where `C` and `D` are parallel, here `Y` is definitely before `Z`.

Git *can* merge this exactly as before:

```
W--X--Y---M   <-- master
       \ /
        Z   <-- branch
```

When Git goes to *combine work*, though, there's no work *on* `master` that isn't also already on `branch`.  So *by default*, **Git** will *not* do this, but instead will do this:

```
W--X--Y--Z   <-- branch, master
```

That is, you'll end up with both labels pointing directly to commit `Z`, without making any new commit `M`.  Once we *erase* the `branch` label, we're left with:

```
W--X--Y--Z   <-- master
```

which leaves us with a simplifying illusion: it looks like we never bothered with any branch.

Again, some people *like* this, some *hate* it, and some are neutral.  Git offers either method.  Some web hosting sites, however, *do not* offer this.  (I have not used GitLab and am not sure what GitLab's defaults are here, and whether it lets you do what Git lets you do.)